# Align image with css

Tags: html, css

I have a blank page just doctype and body.
How to center image vertically and middle within the body ?
The image should be centered in every resolution of monitor.

Comment: [This](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showpost.php?p=1243542&postcount=9) is exactly what you are looking for and [this](http://www.wickham43.supanet.com/tutorial/centeringdivs.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If fixed size image, CSS:

```
img#the-image{
 position:absolute;
 top:50%;
 left:50%;
 margin-left:-HALF_OF_THE_IMAGE_WIDTH;
 margin-top:-HALF_OF_THE_IMAGE_HEIGHT;
}
```